# jQuery will not update the td background color - code included

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery/AJAX to update a table every 10 seconds.  Sometimes the setting for the background color will change and I need to update the background color.  My code changes the HTML as it should but the td is still not updated with the new background color.

```
<table border="1" style = "text-align:center; width:80%" align="center">
    <tr>                
        <td id = "{{item.id}}"  
            style = "background-color:{{item.bgColor.bgColor}}; width:10%">
            <a  id = "{{item.id}}/" class = "bgColor" 
                href="{{item.bgColor.id}}/">
                <span id = "{{item.id}}" class = "bgColor">
                    {{item.bgColor}}
                </span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
var loadTime = Date.now();

function updatePage() 
{   
    $.post(postURL, function(results) 
    {
        for (var loop in results)
        {
            var data = results[loop],
                colorData = $("td#" + data.id),
                colorCell = $("span#" + data.id + ".bgColor"),
                colorLink = $("a#" + data.id + ".bgColor");             

            colorData.css("backgroundColor", data.bgColor.bgColor)
            colorCell.text(data.bgColor.bgColor)
            }
    }, "json");     
    loadTime = Date.now();          
}

var myVar = setInterval( function() {updatePage()}, 10000);
</script>
```

This is the relevant portion of the HTML before the update:

```
<td id = "6"  
    style = "background-color:LightGray; width:10%">
    <a  id = "6" class = "bgColor" 
        href="6/">
        <span id = "6" class = "bgColor">
            LightGray
        </span>
    </a>
</td>
```

This is the relevant portion of HTML after the update:

```
<td id = "6"  
    style = "background-color:Red; width:10%">
    <a  id = "6" class = "bgColor" 
        href="6/">
        <span id = "6" class = "bgColor">
            Red
        </span>
    </a>
</td>
```

the style updated correctly but the background color does not change.
there is no external style sheet associated with the td tag.

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same Id, Ids should be unique.

Comment: I have them labeled the way I want them labeled.  Now about that background color...

Comment: What does the css class `bgColor` set?

Comment: nothing, the class is just to help me find the correct table cell.

Comment: @Musa can you help me with my problem or do you just include critiquing coding styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked your code on JSFiddle by hard coding some things and have it working.  If you say the HTML is updating properly then I would assume it would be working the same. You may have to compare your code to mine to see what the difference is.

Play around with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/mgfqy9ks/3/

```
<table border="1" style = "text-align:center; width:80%" align="center">
        <tr>                
            <td id = "6"  
                style = "background-color:blue; width:10%">
                <a  id = "6/" class = "bgColor" 
                    href="6/">
                    <span id = "6" class = "bgColor" style='color:white;'>
                        Blue
                    </span>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td id = "7"  
                style = "background-color:blue; width:10%">
                <a  id = "7/" class = "bgColor" 
                    href="7/">
                    <span id = "7" class = "bgColor" style='color:white;'>
                        Blue
                    </span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick='updatePage();'>Update</button>

    <script>
        function updatePage() 
    {   
        var results = [{id:6,bgColor:{bgColor:'Orange'}},{id:7,bgColor:{bgColor:'Red'}}];
        for(loop in results){
            var data = results[loop],
                colorData = $("td#" + data.id),
                colorCell = $("span#" + data.id + ".bgColor"),
                colorLink = $("a#" + data.id + ".bgColor");             

            colorData.css("backgroundColor", data.bgColor.bgColor);
            colorCell.text(data.bgColor.bgColor);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Check your console in Developer Tools to see if it's throwing any errors.

Comment: For some reason my code wasn't finding the td.  I was using 2 different windows in my browser one to edit the info and one to see if it would update automatically.  When I looked at the source code it was for some reason showing the source code of the window I was using to make the changes instead of the one I wanted to see the changes in.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Glad you figured it out!